# Liferay - Eclipse alloy tag library error

Tags: eclipse, liferay, alloy-ui

I am developing a portlet that runs on Liferay portal (I have currently Liferay+Tomcat7 bundle, it will later run on JBoss). I am using Eclipse Helios with Liferay IDE and Liferay SDK.

In my .jsp files, I use [Alloy](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/alloy-ui/overview):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
```

Everything works fine - the portlet gets successfully deployed and is shown correctly.
The only problem is, that Eclipse is marking it as an error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://liferay.com/tld/aui"    edit.jsp    /PortletVisual-portlet/docroot  line 2  JSP Problem
```

This is mainly a cosmetic error. Liferay IDE in Eclipse evidently doesnt understand these dependencies, although the project itself works fine. I can live with this "error marker", it doesnt bother me that much. I was just curious if there is a way to fix it.

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT: this is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>PortletVisual-portlet</display-name>

    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-portlet.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
               <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/aui</taglib-uri>
               <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/aui.tld
               </taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/aui</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-aui.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
```

If not working try [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4557395)

Hope I helped! Good luck!!!!

Comment: Tried it but still seeing the same error marker - do I need to have some additional file to support AUI?

Comment: Btw: u can just edit the answer instead of posting a new one :-)

Comment: sorry i am still new in the site i will delete one of them

Comment: try to remove the tag. Some say that in liferay 6.1 its working without it